# Time Management Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, schedule, greedy

I am interested in solving a problem related to time management.

Suppose you are given N intervals, where the i-th interval has a start time and end time, as well as the amount. Each interval represents a constraint that requires (at least) the specified amount of total time doing task i by a machine inside the start and end time of the i-th interval.

The machine can only work on one task at any time but can switch between tasks and come back to another if necessary.

How do you produce a schedule (i.e. allocation of time and task) that satisfies all intervals (i.e. constraints), as well as reporting and minimizing maximum lateness, in the most efficient way?

Also, a variant of the problem:

Each interval is also given a task ID, and if a task is done at some time, it would be counted towards all intervals covering this time and requiring this task. In other words, if multiple intervals that require the same task overlaps, doing the task during the overlapping time will be counted as trying to satisfy all 3 constraints, thus saving some time.

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem as well?

Comment: That's a good description of the problem you're trying to solve, but what's missing is your attempt to solve it.

Comment: You could ask your search engine for `shop floor scheduling` or `shop floor sequencing`.

Comment: Cross site reference: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/86859/64229

Comment: Sure, job scheduling is a problem with many variations and many solutions. Not sure how someone should answer this question. Perhaps you should start with your own thoughts on how to approach just one of these variations.